# run Blender 2.49b on Ubuntu 16.04, 64bit

Tags: python, blender

unfortunately the old Blender 2.49b has still some import/export functions that newer versions of blender do not have.
So I used this program always besides the newest version of Blender.
In the past (until Ubuntu 12.04, 64bit) I had no problem to install old Python 2.6 and than Blender 2.49 worked.
Since I work on Ubuntu 16.04 (64bit) I am not able to use old Blender 2.49. Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

I can think of three options -

1. [Compile blender yourself](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Building_Blender/Linux/Ubuntu/CMake) or find someone that maintains an old version of blender for recent systems. Old versions fail to work as they were compiled against old library versions that are no longer available, some small patching will most likely need to be done.
2. Setup an old system to run blender 2.49. You can install a second system to boot from or create a virtual setup using Xen or Qemu... this will allow you to have the old system that can still run 2.49 when you need to use it.
3. Create an import addon for the current version of blender. Blender's python API was completely changed in 2.50 so any old scripts from 2.49 will need to be re-written for the current version. You can get blender specific scripting help at [blender.stackexchange.com](http://blender.stackexchange.com), if you start by asking for help importing a file format you might get someone pointing you to an addon that has already been made or offering to help you start a new addon.

Comment: on the end the first solution is the best. The second solution is not really helpful for a straight workflow, the third already many others tried but as far as I could find out nobody solved dxf- and 3ds-import really well.

Comment: Both 3ds and dxf import export addons are included with the current blender. If they don't perform as well as the old 2.49 scripts you should [report it as a bug](https://developer.blender.org/maniphest/task/edit/form/1/).

Comment: everybody knows that specially the dxf importer since 2.5 is not far the same as the old one in 2.49. Also in the 3ds importer essential options are missing